# How to control field order in Couchbase N1QL response?

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

How can I organize the json or table that the query show me? This in chouchbase with n1ql.

example:

```
select rol, count(*) as cantidad from PPS where type='Usuario'
group by rol

result
[
  {
    "cantidad": 2,
    "rol": "8847cda1-cf52-4af0-880c-5f7c5a281348"
  },
  {
    "cantidad": 2,
    "rol": "ef35059f-5953-4da7-b5d5-ee0f9a1c893f"
  }
]
```

I need rol first

Comment: Why do you need it first? Are you not parsing the results in your code?

Comment: The order shouldn't matter for a json. Any specific reason you want it that way?

Comment: I need first because I generate a a dynamic grid with this data, y can't parsing or similar  in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but what you're asking for isn't possible. Within each object the fields are returned in sorted order by name. You could rename the fields to something like "1_rol" and "2_cantidad", but that's the best that N1QL can do.

Answer (score 2):

You might also alias the attributes in the select so that they auto order the way you want:
“select rol as 1, candidad as 2...”

Or, order them into an array:
“select [rol, candidad] as _res...”